# Fixed div at the bottom hiding other content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a created a div and that is fixed to bottom. Problem is it is hiding data of html page.

Here is the fiddle.

```css
    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* For the demo only */
    #content {
        background: #D0E5FF;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #00214B;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.8;
    }
    #footer {
        background: #0070FF;
        line-height: 2;
        text-align: center;
        color: #042E64;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #84BAFF;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px #00214B
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    2) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
 
   
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    6) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
      1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    2) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
 
   
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    6) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    </div>
<div id="footer">Footer - Just scroll...</div>
```

Please advise how can show the data that is behind the fixed div.

Comment: You will need to calculate height for your content. Like `#content {height: calc: (100vh - 60px); overflow: auto}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add margin or padding to the content to match the footer height.

```
#content {
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* accomodate for the footer height */
}
```

This works best when you know the height of the footer itself. You could update the padding dynamically with JavaScript if you don't know it beforehand.

The reason it works is that it **creates space** below the content in the **normal element flow**. When the footer is positioned as **fixed**, it is taken **out of this normal flow** and hence you have to **accomodate for its dimensions** to prevent the content in the normal flow to be hidden.

## Padding vs Margin

You can also use `margin-bottom` to create the space. The difference is that with `padding` you create the space **inside** the content `div`, so the background will flow below the footer. With `margin` you create space after the `div` and the background will "end" before the footer.

## Full code snippet

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* For the demo only */
#content {
    background: #D0E5FF;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #00214B;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.8;
}
#footer {
    background: #0070FF;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #042E64;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #84BAFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #00214B
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* accomodate for the footer height */
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    2) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
 
   
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    6) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
      1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    2) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
 
   
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    6) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
    </div>
<div id="footer">Footer - Just scroll...</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, although `100px` is sufficient in this case.

Comment: content still hiding behind footer. Have you seen?

Comment: No it is not, try the code snippet I have just added to my answer :-)

Comment: I have added additional info for `margin` vs `padding` - that might have been the problem you were seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below css for this:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set bottom margin for your content div

```
#content {
background: #d0e5ff none repeat scroll 0 0;
color: #00214b;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.8;
margin-bottom: 60px;/*Add this*/
padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers based on margin or padding should work, but it's a little hack-ish and I wouldn't want to rely on it working in all browsers.  Also notice that even when it works, the right scroll bar runs all the way down the page, even alongside the footer - which is misleading UI since the footer doesn't scroll.

The better solution is to specify a height for the content div and set its `overflow-y` to `auto`.  Specifying the height is the tricky part...

If you're using new enough CSS, flexbox is good for this.

If you're not able to use flexbox, I'd try sizing the height of each div to a fraction of the viewport - i.e. maybe 90vh for the content and 10vh for the footer.  This works best if you can also dynamically size whatever is in the footer.

If you can't use vh units for the footer, then what I used to always fall back on was using JavaScript to figure the size of the footer, subtract that from the height of the viewport, and set the content height accordingly.  It's ugly to involve JavaScript in the layout, but pre-flexbox sometimes that's what was needed.